# Need to modify an existed function that add a string at the end of file

Tags: powershell

I got an answer for a previews question that is working very good here is the link
[Powershell - Need to check if name is ended with a sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395012/powershell-need-to-check-if-name-is-ended-with-a-sign)

The function added 'database/' as needed.
I need to change the function in order to add a string at the beginning of a file name.
Here is the working function:

```
function Append-TFSPath {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Path,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [string] $ChildPath = 'database',
        [char]$Separator = '/'
    )
    $Path = $Path -replace '[\\/]+$'  # trim off final slash(es)
    $ChildPath = $ChildPath -replace '^[\\/]|[\\/]$' -replace '\\', $Separator
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ChildPath) -or ($Path -replace '\\', $Separator) -like "*$ChildPath") {
        "{0}$separator" -f $Path
    }
    else {
        "{0}$separator{1}$Separator" -f $Path, $ChildPath
    }
}
```

How it work right now? :

```
$name = "Test"
$NewName = Append-TFSPath $name

$New Name = Test/database/
```

I need to change it and adding 'database/' at the beginning of the name exactly as it does for the end of the name right now

for an example:

$name = Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql

The result after Append-TFSPath $name should be:

```
database/Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql
```

If the name will be: /Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql
The result should be:

```
database/Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql
```

If the name is already contains /database
The result should be:

```
database/Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this is a good opportunity for a RegEx replace. Combine it with `TrimStart()` and this gets simple fast. I reused the params, and changed the function name a little to better reflect it's usage. Then I build a regex string to match against, and lastly I trim the separator, and both slash and backslash (like you do in your function above), and output the result of the replace. The replace says that if it finds the `$ChildPath` followed by the `$Separator` to replace that with the the `$ChildPath` followed by the `$Separator`, otherwise just replace nothing at the start of the string with the `$ChildPath` followed by the `$Separator` (effectively injecting it at the start of the string).

```
function Prepend-TFSPath {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Path,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [string] $ChildPath = 'database',
        [char]$Separator = '/'
    )
    $RegEx = '^(?:' + [regex]::Escape("$ChildPath") + '[' + [regex]::escape("\/$Separator") + '])?'
    $Path.TrimStart("\/$Separator") -replace $RegEx, "$ChildPath$Separator"
}
```

Then I ran it against some tests:

```
Prepend-TFSPath 'Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql'
Prepend-TFSPath '/Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql'
Prepend-TFSPath 'database/Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql'
Prepend-TFSPath '\Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql'
Prepend-TFSPath 'database\Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql'
```

They all output the same thing:

```
database/Tagging_Domain_Stored%20Procedures_TP_PullOMSDataJobSPs.sql
```

If I change the separator it correctly uses it, and replaces any existing slashes with the new separator at the start of the string.

Comment: Wow thank you @TheMadTechnician.
I think you have a typo for the result where you wrote "They all output" because I ran it with \... and it was replaced with /, I even didn't thought about this case